# Karaf 4, Karaf Profiles, and Docker

Tags: docker, apache-karaf

I read a blog post recently, and some threads related to it, where Jean-Baptiste mentioned working with Docker and Karaf to create custom distributions of apps using Karaf profiles.  I have need to do this as well and would like some direction on how to accomplish this.  I have a working Docker image of Karaf 4.x and now need to have the image automatically deploy my application to it and get a set of configs for it.

1. Are Karaf Profiles documented anywhere?  I know it was a new feature in 4.x but I can't find anything in the Karaf doc and a google search produced nothing of substance about how they work.
2. Are there any working examples of a Docker image/Dockerfile using a Karaf base image and profiles to create a functioning Docker container of a karaf-deployed app?

(I also asked these questions on the apacha karaf mailing lists, but I usually get quicker answers here)

Answer (score 1):

I am facing similar idea and made some progress, however, I still have some challenges. I know its not the final answer but it may provide some progress.

I used this repo as sample for packaging a karaf features into docker https://github.com/ANierbeck/Karaf-Microservices

in principal you want to have the following steps:

1. create karaf feature from your app
2. assemble it to a kar file (a custom karaf distro)
3. deploy the new karaf package to docker

fabric8 has a maven-plugin for doing this which is well documented. https://maven.fabric8.io/

here is the Karaf section about custom assembly builds
https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_custom_distributions

Here is a working sample I crated that deploy to a local docker host. https://github.com/gadieichhorn/play.karaf.calculator/releases